# google places -- autocomplete renturn UNKNOWN_ERROR

Tags: google-places-api

Description:

Occasionally, a 500 error will occur on this interface. When I make the request again with the same input parameter, it is normal and cannot be reproduced. The official document does not give an explanation, prompting UNKNOWN_ERROR

api-url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json

```
request:
{
"input":"東京灣伊",
"key":"XXXXXX",
"sessiontoken":"ceabe5d0-604d-4273-b8a9-5da90b6b2960",
"location":"22.3193039,114.1693611",
"language":"zh-TW"
}
```

response rawStatusCode:500
response body:

```
{
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
}
```

Please help, thanks~

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: "language":"zh-TW"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on my previous comment, but what I meant is programming language. Since you did not put any tag regarding it.

Comment: The programming language is Java